# Router.push('/') would display nothing

Tags: next.js, router

When I try to go to the home page for a user who is not logged in with Next JS, the path moves, but nothing is displayed.

```
  if (!currentFBUser) {
    return Router.push('/')
  }
```

The following error occurred on other pages.

> Unhandled Runtime Error
> Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

How can I fix this?

Comment: remove return !!

Comment: Can you paste the whole file's code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

```
  if (!currentFBUser) {
    Router.push('/')
  }
```

Worked!